# Spring Roo Database Reverse Engineering (DBRE) support for column names with reserved words?

Tags: jpa, spring-roo

I am using Spring Roo to reverse engineer a mysql database scheme in which reserved names (accessible, key, ...) are used for columns names. I am using EclipseLink as JPA implementation.

The data base queries generated for these fields are causing an SQL error since the conflicting field names are not enclosed in back ticks.

In order to avoid these errors the name in the JPA @Column annotation should be quoted like:

```
@Column(name = "\"accessible\"")
```

Other roo commands provide the `--permitReservedWords` option, the `database reverse engineer` command seems to be missing this.

Are column names with reserved words not supported by DBRE?

Comment: It may be issue of ORM provider or database in use. Have you tried using Hibernate? try raising an issue on https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-roo

Comment: Using hibernate as ORM provider does not change anything. The back ticks are still missing for reserved words. I will open a issue ...

Comment: ... here it is https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO-3625